# asp.net watermark on page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, watermark

here I'm trying to get a watermark for my two textbox, supposedly they are Username and Password textbox. I already get the hang of it, using this code:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TbUsername" runat="server" CssClass="tb" Width="170px" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter username'){this.value=''}"
                                onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Enter username'}"></asp:TextBox>
```

and

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TbPassword" runat="server" CssClass="tb" TextMode="Password" Width="170px"
                                onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter password'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Enter password'}"></asp:TextBox>
```

the problem is, I can get the watermark to pop-up only by clicking the textbox first, while I want them to show when the page first started. Is there anyway to do that? Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Html5's Property **Placeholder** for Whatemark

like as below

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TbPassword" runat="server" CssClass="tb" TextMode="Password" Width="170px"
                                placeholder="Your Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

for use of this property you need not to use any external script or do any coding,just what you have do is to put placeholder attribute in textbox

Comment: it will not support for ie 9 and below versions.

Comment: You do need a patch script to support less than IE10, but luckily there are quite a few available, here's one: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: Ah, so that's why my IE can't display it, for I'm looking to build a page that cross-browser-friendly, thank you Mr. @Sagar patel, I'll use that :D God bless you man

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a value when the page is loaded.

Try this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TbUsername.Text = "Enter username";
            TbPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "Enter Password");
        }
    }
```

/Update

Here is the Code for VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        TbUsername.Text = "Enter username"
        TbPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "Enter Password")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should check `IsPostBack` to avoid conflict

Comment: It would be easier to just set the default Text value in the aspx markup

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Solaflex, but what I want is just a watermark, while your solution is in a text form, good answer though! It just inspire me for a new page :)

Answer (score 0):

At your `.vb` file's page load function:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then   
    Me.TbUsername.Text = "Enter username"
    Me.TbPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "Enter Password")
End If
```

This will set `watermark` for the first time the page load.

Another approach is use `jquery` and `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, where do I put the code if I may ask? in the page.aspx.vb or page.vb? I try to put it in page.aspx.vb and I get syntax error, character not valid, etc.

Comment: .Value is not a property of a ASP.NET Textbox
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

Comment: No, my fault too for not mentioning VB.Net in my question and tag, appreciate your help though!

Comment: @AbieGiordano edited, sorry, It has been a long time since my last used of VB.NET, I think it'll work now. Hope this will help you. And if you need code sample for `jquery` approach, just tell me

Comment: It still cause error like this (Error 17 Syntax error.), anything else? :(

Comment: @AbieGiordano Shame on me. I forgot to get rid of the ";". Just remove the `:` in every row and it should work fine. Or you can take a look at Solaflex answer

Comment: Haha, it worked now! thanks for your effort @Doan Cuong, I gain some new knowledge, but I think I'll use placeholder, thank you again for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can use [ajax toolkit water mark](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx) control